# Missing { } in .bbl-file when using '\url' in .bib-file

Tags: bibtex, urls

I have a LaTeX file, including a BibTeX file with items using the `\url` command. But when compiling, for every `\url` command this error rises:

`Undefined control sequence. \newblock{\urlhttp`.

For instance:

```
% tex file
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{some,more}
. . .
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{my.bib}

% my.bib file
@misc{maxmind,
  howpublished = {{\url{https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-services-and-databases}}},
  author = {{MaxMind, Inc.}},
  title = {{MaxMind GeoIP2}},
}

% bbl file
...
\bibitem{maxmind}
{MaxMind, Inc.}
\newblock {MaxMind GeoIP2}.
\newblock {\urlhttps://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-services-and-databases}.
...
```

As you can see, in the `.bbl`-file there are no "curly parentheses" (sorry if this is not the right wording) around the `\url` command.
This also happens when in the bib file there are less parentheses like:

```
howpublished = {\url{https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-services-and-databases}},
```

Does anybody know, how this happens?

Maybe there is a conflict with any other package? Just in case, here are all packages that are used:

```
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[weather]{ifsym}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[digitsep=comma]{siunitx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xspace}
```

I do not know why the curly braces are dropped in the `.bbl`-file but this causes the compiling to crash.
Can you please give me a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: the correct usage of this commad is: `\url{<some URL>}` you need to use curly braces to group the URL inside the command, e.g. `\url{http://www.google.com}`

Comment: @naphaneal -- but the example for the `.bib` file clearly shows braces: `howpublished = {{\url{https://...}}}`.  but they're apparently being removed when that file is processed by bibtex.  it should work, and i can't reproduce the problem.  so there must be a cause that isn't obvious.

Comment: @barbarabeeton very good. my guess is, that there is at least one outdated package which causes this error.

Comment: @naphaneal -- well, in looking closer, i found a glitch in the `algorithm2e` package, namely an unmatched `{` on line 1061, and have tried to notify the author;   but that was enough digging for one day.  because the problem shows up in the bibtex phase, i have to suspect a corrupted `plain.bst` file, but that's so old and stable that i have a hard time figuring out what might have happened.  unless the o.p. has an edited version ... (version in tex live is v0.99b, 8-dec-2010.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I updated the `algorithm2e` package and deleted all temporary files (including the `.bbl` file). Now everything works fine! Thank you again! I am very happy that the document is compiling now without any errors. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood completely the question. But here it goes: if you want to URL's to be typeset with curly braces in the bibliography like this `{tex.stackexchange.com}` you have to use in the `.bib` file `\{` instead of just `{`. Like in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@misc{maxmind,
howpublished = "\{\url{https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-services-and-databases}\}",
author = "MaxMind, Inc.",
title = "MaxMind GeoIP2"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Some random text \cite{maxmind}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Also, by loading the `hyperref` package you already have the command `\url{<some URL>}`. Furthermore, you can use the `natbib` styles which provide the `url` field that can be used directly like `url = "<some-URL>"`. I would also like to recomend the use of `"` instead of curly braces as boundaries of the bibitems fields as curly braces are used to preserve letter cases. [Check the wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management)

Comment: i think, the problem is, that LaTeX (more precisely the compiler) somehow dismisses the braces during the compiling process and causes an error message to show up. it seems to me, that the OP likes to know, why braces are dismissesd even though they are used correctly. my guess is, that an outdated package may cause some sort of incompatibility to some degree.

Comment: @naphaneal I understand now, and I used his exact example in my PC and it worked, maybe that's it, the OP is using something outdated. But, correct me if I'm wrong, could be a solution for him to use `"` instead of curly braces to define the fields.